# regular expression for given file path

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the most recent segment of regexp i tried....but every time it is giving -1,I want it to match with my string str....I have started with basic file path,it should return any value greater than -1 if matched.

```
var str=" c:\folder1\ ";
var n;
var y=/^[a-z]\:\\(folder1)?\\$/g;
n=str.search(y);
alert(n);
```

I want to write it for specific folder names...it should accept both the string given below...
example

File C:\Program Files (x86)\Webdeveloper\dfg.dll

File C:\Program Files\Webdeveloper\dfg.exe

file names will exist with some dll or exe extensions.

/[c]{1}[:]{1}\{1}(folder1){1}\/ shows match for folder1 when i am using http://regex101.com/#javascript,I am passing the string "file c:\folder1\ is corrupted" . but it is not working for whole path string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the path need to be the only thing on the line, and are spaces before and after permitted?

Comment: yeah, spaces are permitted in string....string can be "File C:\Program Files\Webdeveloper\dfg.exe is corrupted"

Comment: Try using regex101.com.  You can plug in a regex and a number of test strings.  Here's a test of @Rex's regex from below:  http://regex101.com/r/oH0bS7

Comment: Can We access and change this link at the same time..I am trying this ^[a-z]\:\\(Program Files)?\\(Webdeveloper)?\\(dfg.exe)?\\$.....match not found.

Comment: string is...."file c:\folder1\ is corrupted"                               Regular Expression is /[c]{1}[:]{1}\\{1}(folder1){1}\\/ it shows " match found" on the link you gave.....                                                                 but when running using above code it is not working,may be because it is using match function and finding subsection of the string.I want to match it whole....can you check this  if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

here  in every '\\',one \ is escape character and other \ is litral.

```
var str="c:\folder1\abc.txt";
var n;
var y=/^(c:\\folder1\\abc\.txt)$/;
n=str.search(y);
alert(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have trailing whitespaces in your source string, so your regexp won't match. Additionally, you should add slashes to your source string to make it capturable. change your code to:

```
var str=" c:\\folder1\\ ";
var n;
var y=/^\s*[a-z]\:\\(folder1)?\\\s*$/g;
str.match(y) // [" c:\folder1\ "]
```

`\f` is a `escape character` which means formfeed.

Comment: I want the string with single '\',it is needed for the given requirements..:(.....I tried adding\s* in start and end but still it is giving -1.......and spaces are part of string...string can be "file c:\folder1\ corrupted"...The code should give the position of c:\folder1\ in the given string.

Comment: if you insist single backslash, i believe it can't be done without server-side help, because obviously `\f` is escaped and won't match any correct regular expression

Comment: oh...still i will try to find a way. their is no option for me to use server side language...i have to make it available in form of java script regular expression only

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression

```
^[C][:]\\[A-Z+a-z ()0-9\\]+[.][a-z]+$
```

[Demo/Testing](http://regex101.com/r/iG6bE8)

Comment: can you give me your test string

Comment: Right now I am trying for the strings which are given in  this test data only.....that is "file c:\folder1\ exist " ,the real string can be like "File C:\Program Files (x86)\  is corrupted".we need to find that the regular expression of the string matches to the string.